# Do we have any Minifier Add-in for visual studio 2005/2008?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, compression, visual-studio-addins

Do we have any Minifier Add-in for visual studio 2005..? that minifies various files inside visual studio.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It doesn't really matter if you do this in programming languages like c# or c++, because the compiler already ignores this. 
Maybe you can look at some obfuscator which also removes whitespace and comments.

Comment: No people. He probably means a minifier for JavaScript

Comment: Yes minifier for javascript/css files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft released their [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=34488) on codeplex today. includes an MS build task and everthing.

Answer (score 1):

See the [results of this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20compressor%20visual%20studio).

Looks like the [YUI Compressor for .Net](http://www.codeplex.com/YUICompressor) is pretty popular, while [this recent blog post details the use of JSMin in Visual Studio](http://encosia.com/2009/05/20/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/).