# Is it possible to minify Javascript, CSS and combine them in deploy time?

Tags: compression, javascript, visual-studio, css, deployment

Is there a feature to minify and combine these files when deploying on Visual Studio?

Comment: do you mean combine them into 1 file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796478/do-we-have-any-minifier-add-in-for-visual-studio-2005-2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an awesome article about this, have a read [here](http://encosia.com/2009/05/20/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: That article doesn't really deal with the deploy aspect of things. For example, how do you deploy files which you create as a post build step?