# Combine minify and compress CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an application on which I used different js libraries and few css files. I want to use a jQuery plugin or a js script in order to combine minify and compress CSS/JavaScript. If someone has a suggestion how to do that please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: This has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216007/how-do-i-minify-css-and-javascript) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883184/ways-to-compress-minify-javascript-files), [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233420/is-it-possible-to-minify-javascript-css-and-combine-them-in-deploy-time) times.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout these...

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a real plugin for that, websites I use:

- http://jscompress.com/
  for Javascript code compression and
- http://www.lotterypost.com/css-compress.aspx
  for css compression.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Mac, there is [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) which is a magic app

Answer (score 2):

Try to use html5boilerplate and then you can get easier the css and js compressed with this tool.
http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/Build-script/

Answer (score 1):

I use Chirpy http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ which is a Visual Studio Add-in for minifying and merging js and css. Don't know if it available for other dev tools though.